How to pass data with ShowPopupAsync in .NET MAUI from calling ViewModel to Popup VieModel?
I tried to follow the Microsoft tutorial on passing data from the calling ViewModel to the Popup ViewModel on the following website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup
Nonetheless, I don't understand exactly how I can pass data. My question:
Does anybody know, how I may pass e.g. string or integer data? Do I need to use ApplyQueryAttributes?
I thought I could pass data like similar when using NavigateToAsync with QueryAttributes, e.g.
NavigationService.NavigateToAsync($"DestinationView?userId={User.ID}"); but it does not seem that trivial.
How may I perform that?

When you call the CloseAsync method you can pass your data in it, as the first argument, it accepts objects and will pretty much accept anything

Yes, the CloseAsync method seems to be useful for passing data from the PopUpViewModel to the calling ViewModel, but I also wanted to pass data from the calling ViewModel to the PopUpViewModel.

this is covered in the docs
this.popupService.ShowPopup<MyPopupViewModel>(onPresenting: viewModel => viewModel.CallSomeMethod(10));

or
this.popupService.ShowPopup<MyPopupViewModel>(onPresenting: viewModel => viewModel.SomeProperty = 10);

